# Log function - why is Log[b,b] not being evaluated to 1?

Tags: evaluation

Have been experimenting with the Log function to demonstrate simple Log relationships such as Log[xy], Log[x+y] etc.

```
Clear[x,y,m,n];
m =b^x;
n = b^y;
Log[b,m]+Log[b,n]
```

The output i get is

```
log(b^y)/log(b)+log(b^x)/log(b)
```

Why is Log[b,b] not being evaluated to 1 ? Also Log[b,b^x]=x so why is it not showing this ? Also the log statements in the output have no base shown ?

I tried

```
Log[b,m]//Trace
```

which gives me

[image: Result]

Simplify doesn't seem to do anything

Thanks
David.

Comment: Replace log by Log (first letter=Uppercase)

Answer (score 10):

`Log[b, b]` does evaluate to 1; your error is in assuming that `Log[b, b^x]` is supposed to simplify automatically to `x`; *Mathematica* assumes that symbols like `b` and `x` are generically **complex numbers** unless told otherwise, and you should know that $\log_b b^x\neq x$ in a large region of the complex plane.

However, you can use `Simplify[]` and assumptions:

```
Simplify[Log[b, b^x], Positive[b] && Element[x, Reals]]
(* x *)
```

FWIW: you are aware of the change-of-base formula? *Mathematica*, for a number of reasons, prefers that all logarithms be expressed as natural logarithms $\log\,x$ ($\ln\,x$ in less-advanced work), and does so. So, `Log[b, x]` is automagically transformed to `Log[x]/Log[b]`. Similar transformations are done for `Log2[x]` and `Log10[x]`.

Comment: Thanks. It did occur to me it was using natural logs but being able to specify assumptions on Simplify is very useful.